# How to control the speed of this JQuery transition

Tags: jquery, performance, transition

I'm very new to JQuery and I'm stuck on this. I have this script to switch between 2 images on hover but I'm finding the switch too jarring. How can I control the speed of the transition?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('img').hover(function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("src");
    var swap = $(this).attr("data-alt-src");
    $(this).attr("src",swap);
    $(this).attr("data-alt-src",current);
  }, function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("src");
    var swap = $(this).attr("data-alt-src");
    $(this).attr("data-alt-src",current);
    $(this).attr("src",swap);
  });
})
```

Comment: So you want to fade out the previous image and face in the new one? You can animate opacity if that is what you need.

Comment: Yea pretty much. Right now the the change is too sudden so I'd like to smooth out the transition. Basically like the duration/timing for CSS animations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make transitions use animate:

```
 $( "#yourImg" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
 }, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
 });
```

If you want to delay the transition you can use:

```
setTimeout()
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I use that to change between images on hover?

Comment: Or actually easier with CSS, http://jsfiddle.net/Xm2Be/2/ is this the result you want ?

Comment: Boom. That's perfect. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm glad I helped